# Accessing Store's value inside loop in SvelteJS v3

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

i am building a dashboard from an array of objects that have `store` as some of its property. each store are updated independently from different source.

my problem is i am unable to read the `store` value inside `each` loop.

to simplify the following code sample, i use `tweened` instead of `store`

the following code also available in Svlete REPL
https://svelte.dev/repl/9a17102e7d32471a940ba007e5b56db0?version=3.6.7

```html
<script>
    import { tweened } from 'svelte/motion';

    const data = [{
        label: 'one',
        value: tweened(0)
    }, {
        label: 'two',
        value: tweened(0)
    }]

</script>

<ul>
    {#each data as item}
        <li>{item.label} ({item.$value})</li>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

the `{item.$value}` part returns `undefined`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't currently possible — there's an issue open for 'contextual stores' ([#2016](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2016)) which would let you do this sort of thing...

```html
<ul>
  {#each data as { label, value }}
    <li>{label} ({$value})</li>
  {/each}
</ul>
```

...but we're not there yet. In the meantime the workaround is to pass the store to a component:

```html
<ul>
  {#each data as item}
    <ListItem label={item.label} value={item.value}/>
  {/each}
</ul>
```

Inside the component, you'd have `export let label, value`, and you could use `$value` as intended.